# custom dhcp records windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, dhcp

I am going through a setup of [thinstation](http://thinstation.org) and i am in a situation where i need to add a custom DHCP record so when i computer starts up it knows where the TFTPD server when it gets DHCP.

I've had a snoop around and i cant seem to see the ability to add a custom record, is there a way to do this on windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open up the DHCP management console under administrative tools
- If your DHCP server isn't listed then add it
- If the server was listed you may need to double click on it to get windows to establish the connection to the DHCP server
- Right-click on the server name
- If you need to add a vendor/user class then:

  - Choose 'Define Vendor Class' or 'Define User Class'
- Else Choose 'Predefined Options and Values'

  - Add any options/values you need.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using DHCP option 150 (tftp-server)?  It looks to be a tentative assignment so not entirely sure what the support for this option is.  Have a shot, anyway.